# Nodes are moving. Can it be called a standing wave?

Tags: wave

Please see the following youtube video.

https://youtu.be/MJKfyLfY9Pg

[image]

It is a lossy transmission line.

The resultant wave of incident and reflected wave is also moving.

In a standing wave, neither the motion of the vibration (node) nor the position of the ship (antinode) shifts spatially. Isn't it?

wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave

Comment: you have the figures from gnuplot yourself. Why film them with a phone camera in bad lightning situation, then upload that to youtube, **then** figure out how to take a screenshot and thus post a screenshot of your video of your phone filming a creen? Simply  generate a gif and upload it here instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899696/4433386

Comment: @Marcus Müller   I'm not the maker of the video. I know that the Quality of the video is bad. But . Can't you discern the contens of video? Or Can't you understand my question?

Comment: I'm honestly having a bad time discerning the contents of the video. Your question seems to be, even without the video "can I call it a standing wave if the nodes are moving", and you seem to know the answer to that, so I assume there's some fine detail in the video that motivates the question.

Comment: @Marcus Müller    I don't know the answer to my question.  Why ask a question if I know the answer?  You're such a strange person.  Why are you making assumptions like that?   The question is the question.

Comment: It seems to me that the author may be using the phrase "standing wave" in a nonstandard way. They seem to be comparing the net/combined voltage wave on a lossless transmission line with a reflection -- a true standing wave -- with what you get when the line is lossy so the reflected wave has lower amplitude. It's not really a standing wave as I understand the term. But we would need more context to say more about what the author is trying to communicate here.

Comment: @Glenn Willen
    Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been helpful to provide more context about where the video came from, since the video itself is very low quality and explains little. It seems to be from this site:

http://www.abhipod.com/teachingpage/notes/standingwaves/standingwaves.html

The author seems to distinguish between (1) "standing waves", which are seen in the presence of reflection on a lossless transmission line, and do not move; and (2) "standing wave patterns", which are seen in the presence of reflection on a lossy transmission line, and do move.

As far as I know, "standing wave pattern" is not standard terminology, used in this way. Wikipedia seems to call this a "partial standing wave": https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave and some other sources do as well (e.g.
https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PartialStandingWaves/ )

In any case, the answer to your question is no: the nodes of a standing wave do not move. The author is talking about a related concept, which they call a "standing wave pattern", and other sources call a "partial standing wave".

Comment: Wow.....  It seems accurate... and You are amazing...  Thank you so much!!!